# how can i visit and manipulate a html table by find function and its id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The source code  site:[enter link description here](http://github.com/ChiChou/libFan/blob/master/js/inject.js)

```
var table = $(data).find("table").removeAttr("width");
```

I can using the table,beacause there is only one table tag :... .
But how can visit a table(the table have a id) if there are two table in the html,eg:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" id="item">...</table>
```

Thank you for thinking my question.Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the id in the find:

```
var table = $(data).find("table#item").removeAttr("width");
```